# moviepy problem with ImageMagick: delegate library support not built-in

Tags: python, delegates, imagemagick, built-in, moviepy

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and when I try to run a Python code that uses the moviepy library, it returns an error related to ImageMagick:

My simple code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

text = TextClip("test", fontsize=24, color='white')

text = text.set_duration(10)

background = ColorClip((1920, 1080), color=(0, 0, 0))

background = background.set_duration(10)

test_video = CompositeVideoClip([background, text.set_pos(('right', 'bottom'))])
```

The error when I run `python3 code.py` (I'm using virtual env called `ttenv`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/project/ttenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 1137, in __init__
    subprocess_call(cmd, logger=None)
  File "/home/myuser/project/ttenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/tools.py", line 54, in subprocess_call
    raise IOError(err.decode('utf8'))
OSError: convert: delegate library support not built-in '/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/2067.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
convert: no images defined `PNG32:/tmp/tmpg4dfl7dq.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3342.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/project/make-video.py", line 4, in <module>
    text = TextClip("test", fontsize=24, color='white')
  File "/home/pedro/tt-project/ttenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 1146, in __init__
    raise IOError(error)
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

convert: delegate library support not built-in '/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/2067.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
convert: no images defined `PNG32:/tmp/tmpg4dfl7dq.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3342.
.

.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect
```

My `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policymap [
  <!ELEMENT policymap (policy)*>
  <!ATTLIST policymap xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
  <!ELEMENT policy EMPTY>
  <!ATTLIST policy xmlns CDATA #FIXED '' domain NMTOKEN #REQUIRED
    name NMTOKEN #IMPLIED pattern CDATA #IMPLIED rights NMTOKEN #IMPLIED
    stealth NMTOKEN #IMPLIED value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<!--
  Configure ImageMagick policies.

  Domains include system, delegate, coder, filter, path, or resource.

  Rights include none, read, write, execute and all.  Use | to combine them,
  for example: "read | write" to permit read from, or write to, a path.

  Use a glob expression as a pattern.

  Suppose we do not want users to process MPEG video images:

    <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="mpeg:decode" />

  Here we do not want users reading images from HTTP:

    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />

  The /repository file system is restricted to read only.  We use a glob
  expression to match all paths that start with /repository:

    <policy domain="path" rights="read" pattern="/repository/*" />

  Lets prevent users from executing any image filters:

    <policy domain="filter" rights="none" pattern="*" />

  Any large image is cached to disk rather than memory:

    <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="1GP"/>

  Use the default system font unless overwridden by the application:

    <policy domain="system" name="font" value="/usr/share/fonts/favorite.ttf"/>

  Define arguments for the memory, map, area, width, height and disk resources
  with SI prefixes (.e.g 100MB).  In addition, resource policies are maximums
  for each instance of ImageMagick (e.g. policy memory limit 1GB, -limit 2GB
  exceeds policy maximum so memory limit is 1GB).

  Rules are processed in order.  Here we want to restrict ImageMagick to only
  read or write a small subset of proven web-safe image types:

    <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="*" />
    <policy domain="filter" rights="none" pattern="*" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="*" />
-->
    <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="{GIF,JPEG,PNG,WEBP}" />

<policymap>
  <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="512MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="list-length" value="128"/> -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="1GiB"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="module" rights="none" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" /> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="cache" name="memory-map" value="anonymous"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="cache" name="synchronize" value="True"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="max-memory-request" value="256MiB"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="shred" value="2"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="font" value="/path/to/font.ttf"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="pixel-cache-memory" value="anonymous"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="shred" value="2"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- not needed due to the need to use explicitly by mvg: -->
  <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <!-- use curl -->
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />
  <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
  <!-- disable ghostscript format types -->
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS2" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS3" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="TEXT" />
</policymap>
```

My `/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts` permissions:
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root` for all files

I've already tried this solutions:

1. Updating it to the latest version running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. Giving permissions on `/tmp` and on font's file to my user
3. Changing some configurations on `policy.xml`

**Edit:**

- The `file /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb` output:

  ```
  /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb: PostScript Type 1 font program data (NimbusMonL-Regu 1.06)
  ```
- The `ls -l /user/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb` output:

  ```
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 94786 jan  3 15:54 /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb
  ```
- The `convert -debug all -font /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb -pointsize 48 label:"Hello World" hello.png` output:

  ```
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: utility.c/ExpandFilenames/973/Configure
  Command line: convert {-debug} {all} {-font} {/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb} {-pointsize} {48} {label:Hello World} {hello.png}
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Module; rights=Unrecognized; pattern="LABEL" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Coder; rights=Read; pattern="LABEL" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Pixel convert[4089]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6307/Pixel
  Hello World[07ffffff]
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Pixel convert[4089]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6191/Pixel
  Hello World[07ffffff]
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Pixel convert[4089]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6288/Pixel
    0: red (update)
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Pixel convert[4089]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6288/Pixel
    1: green (update)
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Pixel convert[4089]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6288/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1B/0B/15.4046GiB
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 12B/12B/7.70229GiB
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Cache convert[4089]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3798/Cache
  open Hello World[0] (Heap Memory, 1x1x3 12B)
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Cache convert[4089]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1064/Cache
  destroy Hello World[0]
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1074/Resource
  Memory: 12B/0B/7.70229GiB
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Width: 264B/0B/409.6PiB
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.1.0//config-Q16HDRI/locale.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/home/pedro/.config/ImageMagick/locale.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1177/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "/usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.1.0//config-Q16HDRI/english.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Locale convert[4089]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/home/pedro/.config/ImageMagick/english.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1177/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "/usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7/english.xml" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Exception convert[4089]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/2067/Exception
  delegate library support not built-in '/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb' (Freetype)
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Annotate convert[4089]: annotate.c/RenderPostscript/2193/Annotate
  Font /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb; pointsize 48
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/584/Resource
  ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/641/Resource
  /tmp/magick-jFaf2l7OrlfUHLbBH6k8gV6rt2rScPzL
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Module; rights=Unrecognized; pattern="PS" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="/tmp/magick-jFaf2l7OrlfUHLbBH6k8gV6rt2rScPzL" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Blob convert[4089]: blob.c/OpenBlob/3453/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Cache convert[4089]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1064/Cache
  destroy 
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Coder; rights=Read; pattern="PS" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="/tmp/magick-jFaf2l7OrlfUHLbBH6k8gV6rt2rScPzL" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Blob convert[4089]: blob.c/OpenBlob/3453/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/584/Resource
  ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/641/Resource
  /tmp/magick-faN1FzvtOzDGwqP1YcnLHRxwC4IEtWRQ
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishUniqueFileResource/1113/Resource
  /tmp/magick-faN1FzvtOzDGwqP1YcnLHRxwC4IEtWRQ
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/584/Resource
  ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/641/Resource
  /tmp/magick-YZX9RZBSyTVr3ShLu0CNAr_BqGDvAgCI
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7/delegates.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.1.0//config-Q16HDRI/delegates.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/delegates.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/delegates.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/695/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/home/pedro/.config/ImageMagick/delegates.xml"
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Configure convert[4089]: delegate.c/LoadDelegateCache/2094/Configure
  Loading delegate configuration file "/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/delegates.xml" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/584/Resource
  ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireUniqueFileResource/641/Resource
  /tmp/magick-IjaxzuCSMrQfTLIUilHJYLnuZLFP8Sjb
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishUniqueFileResource/1113/Resource
  /tmp/magick-IjaxzuCSMrQfTLIUilHJYLnuZLFP8Sjb
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Delegate; rights=Execute; pattern="gs" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.063 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishUniqueFileResource/1113/Resource
  /tmp/magick-YZX9RZBSyTVr3ShLu0CNAr_BqGDvAgCI
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.063 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishUniqueFileResource/1113/Resource
  /tmp/magick-faN1FzvtOzDGwqP1YcnLHRxwC4IEtWRQ
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="/tmp/magick-IjaxzuCSMrQfTLIUilHJYLnuZLFP8Sjb1" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Blob convert[4089]: blob.c/OpenBlob/3453/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Cache convert[4089]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1064/Cache
  destroy 
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Policy convert[4089]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/647/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="/tmp/magick-IjaxzuCSMrQfTLIUilHJYLnuZLFP8Sjb1" ...
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Blob convert[4089]: blob.c/OpenBlob/3453/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Cache convert[4089]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1064/Cache
  destroy 
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Exception convert[4089]: constitute.c/ReadImage/741/Exception
  no decode delegate for this image format `'
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishUniqueFileResource/1113/Resource
  /tmp/magick-IjaxzuCSMrQfTLIUilHJYLnuZLFP8Sjb1
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishUniqueFileResource/1113/Resource
  /tmp/magick-IjaxzuCSMrQfTLIUilHJYLnuZLFP8Sjb1
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Cache convert[4089]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1064/Cache
  destroy convert: delegate library support not built-in '/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/2067. convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/RelinquishUniqueFileResource/1113/Resource
  /tmp/magick-jFaf2l7OrlfUHLbBH6k8gV6rt2rScPzL
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Annotate convert[4089]: annotate.c/GetTypeMetrics/933/Annotate
  Metrics: text: Hello World; width: 0; height: 0; ascent: 0; descent: 0; max advance: 0; bounds: 0,0  0,0; origin: 0,0; pixels per em: 0,0; underline position: 0; underline thickness: 0
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Resource convert[4089]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Height: 0B/0B/409.6PiB
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Cache convert[4089]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1064/Cache
  destroy 
  2023-01-05T04:13:50+00:00 0:00.064 0.000u 7.1.0 Exception convert[4089]: convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3342/Exception
  no images defined `hello.png' convert: no images defined `hello.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3342.
  ```
- Trying to use a `.ttf` font with `convert -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansFallbackFull.ttf -pointsize 48 label:"Hello World" hello.png` returns an error too:

  ```
  convert: delegate library support not built-in '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansFallbackFull.ttf' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/2067.
  convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
  convert: no images defined `hello.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3342.
  ```

Comment: Why are you telling us the permissions on `/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts` when your policy.xml specifies `/usr/share/fonts/favorite.ttf`? Have you installed `libfreetype`? Did you try a simple command with **ImageMagick** from the Command-line that uses a font?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I informed the permissions of this directory because they refer to the error that was given to me. The path you mentioned is actually not being applied as it is commented out in the policy.xml, which means it is using the default path. But even specifying ```/usr/share/fonts``` manually doesn't work. The ```libfreetype``` package is already installed and commands like ```convert -font /path/to/myfont.ttf -pointsize 48 label:"Hello World" hello.png``` return a similar problem.

Comment: Can you click [edit] and add in the output from `file /path/to/myfont.ttf` and `ls -l /path/to/myfont.ttf` and `convert -debug all -font ... -pointsize 48 label:"Hi" hello.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell sure, it's done

Comment: Mmm... can you try with a TrueType `.ttf` font rather than `.pfb`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried and doesn't worked too. It's on edit now